# Compare two expression tree for semantically equivalence

Tags: compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I have the problem to compare two expression trees and decide if they are semantically equivalent.

Background:

In my open source compiler for the OpenPEARL programming language there are
slices for bit-strings and character-strings, which can have the form:

```
variable.BIT(expr:expr+42)
```

In this case "expr" must evaluate to the same value.

Example:

Let a and b some numerical variable with values known at runtime:

```
Expression1: (a+2)*(b/8)
Expression2: (1+a+1)*(b/(4*2))
```

For solving this I need to evaluate the constant expression part (which is already done and working), normalize both trees  and after that perform a recursive tree comparision. By normalization I mean to reorder the nodes according to their algebraic properties.

Any idea, hint or discussion is welcomed!

Comment: You need to build an AST (Asbtract Syntax Tree) and perform the comparison on that... ANTLR won't do that for you though

Comment: As Raven already mentioned: ANTLR isn't going to facilitate the "after parsing" stage. Better re-tag your question as to attract the right crowd.

Comment: @Bart: Do you have a suggestion for re-tagging my questions? Thanx.

Comment: @MarcelSchaible done!

Comment: @Bart Kiers: Thanx!